# How to use kivy development in python for android?

Tags: kivy

I want to use some features in kivy 1.9
so I installed it on my linux ,

```
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.9.0-dev
```

but when i package it to android emulator I read this using logcat

```
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
```

so after I clone kivy repository
what is the proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `kivy==master` in the buildozer requirements line, e.g. `requirements = docutils,kivy==master`. It will automatically download and use the master branch.

You could also set the `P4A_kivy_DIR` environment variable to point at your clone, but there's no need to do this unless you are modifying the kivy source yourself.

Comment: I want to use Window.softinput_mode , which you mentioned it in another answer ..